# Running a Python + Behave automation project and trying to execute steps inside another steps

Tags: python, automation

```
@step(u'Child step')
def login_to_something(context):
    context.execute_steps(u'parent step 1')
    context.execute_steps(u'parent step 2')
```

It is unable execute_steps as mentioned above for parent step 1 and it throws the following error:-
"behave.parser.ParserError: Failed to parse "

Comment: I have tried different ways to resolve this:- tried calling the step in " ", ' ' and with u" ", f" ". Even tried to add the following imports:-                                                                     
 import parse
use_step_matcher("parse"), but nothing is working.

Comment: Also followed this link to check whether my steps are fine or not https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial08.html

Answer (score 2):

When the Behave engine is not able to identify or distinguish the steps within a step, probably the error you see. Then there is something probably not in semantic as expected by engine.

I got your point, yes the preposition should not matter and just the step is good enough.. But there is something missing in expected semantic so the parser error.

```
 def login_to_something(context):
    context.execute_steps('''
        when write the step 1 here
        then write the step 2 here
    '''
    )
```

I'm unable to get from more information shared by you in problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Indentations of your feature file. We also faced this issues multiple times.